# how to convert specified time in particular timezone?

Tags: java, timezone

I am living in India so my timezone is IST so when I want to fix meeting with the UK client then I just put my time in field like 10 A.M to 11 A.M. Now How to convert this in GMT0000 that is UK time zone?

Basically I have textfied to enter time then after inserted there is one dropdown box that is containing all available timezone then when I select UK timezone then how to convert this process using Java?

Thanks in advance.. tell me to solve my issue..
Note: I don't want to do this manually? cause of selection it will be converted? that is my task.. hope you understand my problem..

Regards..

Comment: java != javascript ==> make up your mind...

Comment: whichever is easy? I have the knowledge of javascript also.. so tell me which is easy for you to guide me? @assylias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

India time is `GMT + 5.30`. Then `10.00 -5.30` can consider as `GMT` time.

In java you can do something like this

```
   DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
   Date dateIST=df.parse("10:00"); // india time
   df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
   System.out.println(df.format(dateIST));// This is UK time
```

Comment: @Ruchira..sorry I can't get you? :( what are you trying to say?

Comment: thanks a lot@ruchira.. I accept your answer now can you upvote my question because I dont think its downvoted question? :(

Answer (score 1):

(JAVA answer) In textfield(s) you just need to enter your local time. Take an input from that textfield(s) and pass it in following code.

```
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));//or whatever timezone u want.
    String gmtStrDate = simpleDateFormat.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

Or you may find this code suited to your need (your question is unclear):

```
    SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    Date date = inputFormat.parse("time from textfield");//like 11:44
    inputFormat.setTimeZone((TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST")));

    SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    outputFormat.setTimeZone((TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")));
    String outputText = outputFormat.format(date);
```

Now outputText is your desired time in UK format.

Note : Here i assumed you are entering time in textfield like 13:44. You can accordingly change that in formatters.

Comment: @Raju..suppose I entered value in textbox like 8:00 in IST, I want to convert this time in another timezone? how it possible? based on the selection of dropdownbox?

Comment: In your program you can always have the text box value in a variable. Just parse that value with "inputFormat" formatter and apply your local timezone. Later you can convert it to another timezone as i have done above, and put in dropdown. Are you asking me to write dropdown code ?